# JAVA JPA optional field(column)

Tags: java, database, jpa, orm, entity

I have one abstract class which is extended by two classes:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ConfigElement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "Code")
    private String code;

    @Basic()
    @Column(name = "ParameterType")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ParameterTypeEnum parameterType;

}


@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class ConfigRate extends ConfigElement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "rate", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
    private BigDecimal rate;
}
```

And

```
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
public class Parameter extends ConfigElement implements Serializable {

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CurrentValue")
    private String currentValue;
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is that field **parameterType** only appears in **Parameter** Table and i wan't to make it optional so when query from **ConfigRate** executes it ignores **parameterType** and when query executes from **Parameter** entity it uses **parameterType** field, I added annotation `@Basic(optional=true)`, but it doesn't work and throws this error:

> Unknown column 't0.ParameterType' in 'field list'

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour in JPA ?

By the way i'm using EclipseLink JPA implementation.

Comment: If it should only exist in Parameter, then put it in Parameter. Not in the superclass, that is also the superclass of ConfigRate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move annotation from paramterType field to setter method in Parameter class like below

```
@Setter
@Getter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ConfigElement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "Code")
    private String code;

    private ParameterTypeEnum parameterType;

}

@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
public class Parameter extends ConfigElement implements Serializable {

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CurrentValue")
    private String currentValue;        

    @Column(name = "ParameterType")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public ParameterTypeEnum getParameterType() {
        return super.parameterType;
    }
}
```

Comment: No you cannot. You annotate fields OR getters, but not both.

Comment: then move all field annotation in base class to getter method